# R: Passing a single list of matrices as input to a function that requires at least 2 input matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am trying to use the R [mnnCorrect](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/scran/man/scran.pdf) function (from the scran package). It requires at least 2 input matrices to work.

```
# install package
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("scran")
# example matrix 1
B1 <- matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol=50)
# example matrix 2
B2 <- matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol=50)
# function below works fine
out <- mnnCorrect(B1, B2)
```

However, I am trying to supply these matrices as a list like so (more convenient for automating the process with a variable number of matrices):

```
mat_list=list()
mat_list[["Mat1"]]=B1
mat_list[["Mat2"]]=B2
str(mat_list)
List of 2
 $ Mat1: num [1:200, 1:50] 1.107 -0.828 1.559 -1.353 0.667 ...
 $ Mat2: num [1:200, 1:50] -0.231 0.894 0.369 1.606 -1.346 ...

# This works fine
out <- mnnCorrect(mat_list$Mat1, mat_list$Mat2)

# These do not work
out <- mnnCorrect(mat_list)
Error in mnnCorrect(mat_list) : at least two batches must be specified

out <- mnnCorrect(cat(paste(gsub("^","mat_list$",names(mat_list)),collapse=", "))
Error in mnnCorrect(mat_list) : at least two batches must be specified

out <- mnnCorrect(capture.output(cat(paste(gsub("^","mat_list$",names(mat_list)),collapse=", ")))
Error in mnnCorrect(mat_list) : at least two batches must be specified

library(dplyr)
cat(paste(gsub("^","mat_list$",names(mat_list)),collapse=", ") %>% mnnCorrect(.)
mat_list$Mat1, mat_list$Mat2Error in mnnCorrect(.) : at least two batches must be specified
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, you use the function do.call for that. Here is an example:

```
do.call(mnnCorrect, mat_list)
```

See also the help page ?do.call .